# Is connectedness varies with change of metric in metric topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am confused about a fact of topology that " connectedness varies as the induced metric changes on a metric topology"

I hope answer should be no .  But I want a proper justification. 
Please help.

Comment: Varies as ... makes no sense.  If the metric is changed, connectedness of the space can change.  Change the usual metric for R to the discrete metric, for example.

Comment: Your previous question was from Munkres. If this is also, what page?

Comment: @WillJagy , that query comes on my mind , solving 23.8 on munkars page 150 , in uniform topology there we can find a separation of  $\mathbf{R}^\omega  $ , as $A $ and  $X-A  $ . Where  $A $ be the set of all bounded sequence. I searching connectedness of it on some other topology.  So, that query arises on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is connected in its standard topology induced by its usual metric. But $\mathbb{R}$ is disconnected in the discrete topology (any subset is open), which is induced by the discrete metric $\rho:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\rho(x,y)=0$ if $x\neq y$ and $\rho(x,x)=1$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

Connectednes is a topological property. It solely depends on the topology of the space. So, if you change your metric the topology induced by new metric may be different from the topology induced by the previous metric. So, a connected space may become disconnected in the metric and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks,  I also want to know is there any metric that I can induced to show  $\mathbf{R}^\omega  $ is connected. Where it is disconnected on uniform topology

Comment: Have you tried using product topology in $R^{\omega}$?